# XHTML - adding new elements

Tags: html, css, validation, xhtml, markup

How can I add new tags to the xhtml document without making the markup 'invalid'?

for eg:

instead of `<span class="time">` I'd like to use `<time>`. Is this possible? because I've seen a facebook app do something like this.

Comment: I think Facebook uses JavaScript to find those tags and replace them with something else. Those are normally used to make things user-friendly and then replace them with the more complicated tags that no one wants to type out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a new namespace for your invented elements:

```
<html xmlns:foo="urn:my-namespace">
...
<foo:time>...</foo:time>
```

or

```
<html>
...
<time xmlns="urn:my-namespace">...</time>
```

Of course, this isn't going to make an ounce of sense to your browser but I presume you have good reasons to want to do this.

Comment: actually I just want to make the code smaller and more intuitive :)
Is this a bad idea?

Comment: It's not really a bad idea... but I doubt it'll work as expected in most browsers. Also, the `time` element (and many others) is available in HTML5. If you're not gearing up to use that already, you should be soon.